# Write csv file with \r in Scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to write a csv file in spark with line ending with \r - carriage return. By default lines are ending with \n - newline. Any idea to change this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use LineSep option.

```
df.write.format("csv").option("lineSep", "\r").save(path)
```

Comment: is this lineSep works for spark 2.4 version as well? I write using option("lineSep","\r\n") but still it is writing it will \n only.